# Error when showing captcha in PHP

Tags: php, captcha

I have following  php script for showing the captcha in a web page, captcha is showing properly in my local apache server but when I uploaded in to the web hosting server I get an error as mentioned below, please help

```
<?php
session_start();

$str = "";
$length = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    // these numbers represent ASCII table (small letters)
    $str .= chr(rand(97, 122));
}

//md5 letters and saving them to session
$letters = md5($str);
$_SESSION['letters'] = $letters;

//determine width and height for our image and create it
$imgW = 150;
$imgH = 50;
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);

//setup background color and border color
$backgr_col = imagecolorallocate($image, 238,239,239);
$border_col = imagecolorallocate($image, 208,208,208);

//let's choose color in range of purple color
$text_col = imagecolorallocate($image, rand(70,90),rand(50,70),rand(120,140));

//now fill rectangle and draw border
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $imgW, $imgH, $backgr_col);
imagerectangle($image, 0, 0, $imgW-1, $imgH-1, $border_col);

//save fonts in same folder where you PHP captcha script is
//name these fonts by numbers from 1 to 3
//we shall choose different font each time
$fn = rand(1,3);
$font = $fn . ".ttf";

//setup captcha letter size and angle of captcha letters
$font_size = $imgH / 2.0;
$angle = rand(-15,15);
$box = imagettfbbox($font_size, $angle, $font, $str);
$x = (int)($imgW - $box[4]) / 2;
$y = (int)($imgH - $box[5]) / 2;
imagettftext($image, $font_size, $angle, $x, $y, $text_col, $font, $str);

//now we should output captcha image
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy ($image);
?>
```

And the error is

```
Error: Image corrupt or truncated: http://url/captcha.php
Source File: http://url/captcha.php
```

Comment: Remove the ending `?>` tag, make sure error logging is on, check the error logs.

Comment: Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of the script before `session_start()` and then comment out the `header('Content-Type: image/png');` line and try loading the image in the browser.  You should see some error messages from PHP explaining the problem.  Best guess is that FreeType (ttf functions) are not installed.

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem, that using CAPTCHA (with imagepng()) worked on one machine, but not on the remote server. I checked the PNG file in a hex editor and found an extra 0D0A in the first 4 bytes. I called ob_clean() right before imagepng(), problem solved.